# Apache Drill view.drill json syntax to describe complex data types

Tags: apache-drill

Does the JSON fields array in the view.drill file created by create view support describing an ARRAY, STRUCT type?

Want to define views of PARQUET files so they are described by the JDBC driver (DatabaseMetadata.getTables, getColumns...). Want to project the columns of the PARQUET file as the actual type (i.e. INTEGER) versus leaving Drill to describe them as the ANY type. Unfortunately, that requires CAST ( as ) and the target types supported by CAST does not include ARRAY or STRUCT.

Hence, if the view.drill file can be externally defined without requiring a CAST and supported complex types would build them programmatically.